# MySql - how to combine where clauses for both tables for one to many join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

```
sellers
id|name

locations
id|seller_id|name
```

Now I want to get sellers and join locations and combine attributes from both tables in where clause.

Initial query is :

```
SELECT 
    sellers.id
FROM sellers
JOIN locations.seller_id = sellers.id
```

I must add one more part because I don't want duplicated data :

```
SELECT 
    sellers.id
FROM sellers
JOIN locations on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
WHERE (
    SELECT id from locations
    WHERE locations.seller_id = sellers.id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Now I can do the following

```
SELECT 
    sellers.id
FROM sellers
JOIN locations on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
WHERE (
    SELECT id from locations
    WHERE locations.seller_id = sellers.id
    LIMIT 1
)
AND (
    sellers.name = 'test'
    OR
    locations.name = 'test'
)
```

- problem here is that MySql will join first location and if name of that location is not "test" and there is location with name "test" for that seller it would not be not in results.

Any ideas?

UPDATED :

example with data :

```
sellers
id|name
1|test
2|test2


locations
id|seller_id|name
1|1|test3
2|2|test4
3|2|test
4|2|test


result should be 
[1, 2] but with my query it is [1]
```

Comment: `JOIN locations.seller_id = locations.id` does not make any sense here. You probably need `JOIN locations.seller_id = sellers.id`

Comment: Your query is full of Syntax errors; What are you trying to actually achieve ?

Comment: sry I updated queries

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your SQL simpler, the answer becomes simpler.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sellers.*
FROM sellers
    INNER JOIN locations on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
WHERE
    sellers.name = 'test'
    OR
    locations.name = 'test'
```

Comment: with your query result with my example in UPDATED section is [1, 2, 2] but it should be [1, 2], I can add group by but then only_full_group_by error appears, I know hot to suppress that error but I would prefer solution without group by...

Comment: @fico7489 Either you have mistyped my query, or there is additional information you have not provided which is altering the result.

Comment: with your query second seller would be duplicated in results

Comment: I forgot that I did't put ORDER BY in my example query, but yes your query would work without ORDER BY locations.SOMETHING, awesome...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group By` with `Having`:

```
SELECT sellers.id, 
       sellers.name, 
       SUM(locations.name = 'test') AS has_test_location 
FROM sellers
    INNER JOIN locations on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
GROUP BY sellers.id, sellers.name 
HAVING sellers.name = 'test' OR 
       has_test_location
```

Comment: hm, nice, I think that above query would work, although I would prefer something simpler, but I assume there there is no nothing simpler :(

Comment: @fico7489 without subqueries, this is the simplest I think can be achieved.

Comment: @Strawberry just a variable name so that OP can  understand what it is used for.